# OPL Constraint to pyomo ConstraintList constraint for concrete model

Tags: pyomo, opl

Could someone help me convert these OPL constraints into equivalent Pyomo ConstraintList constraints for a concrete model:

opl code:

```
ct_b:
    sum(i in items)cost[i]["s3"] <= 0.4*sum(i in items, j in suppliers)cost[i][j]*q[i][j];
```

my code:

```
    model.b_constr = ConstraintList()
    model.b_constr.add(sum (model.cost[i, 'S3'] for i in items) <=  0.4*(sum(model.cost[i,j]*model.q[i,j] for i in items for j in suppliers ))
```

opl code:

```
    forall(i in items: i!="B" && i!="C"){
      ct_d_3:
      sum(j in suppliers)x[i][j]==4;
    }
```

my code:

```
model.ct_d_3 = ConstraintList()
model.ct_d_3.add(for i in items if i!="B" && i!="C":
        model.d_constr_3.add(sum (model.q[i,j] for j in suppliers) ==4))
```

I am getting syntax error in formulating above code in Pyomo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: Already tried ChatGPT! Satisfactory result not obtained.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a perfect task for e.g. chatGPT:

Prompt: Could you translate the following OPL constraints to Pyomo using pyomo’s ConstraintList: forall(j in suppliers){
ct_c_f1:
x["F"][j]>=q["F"][j]/M;
ct_c_f2:
q["F"][j]>=x["F"][j]/M;
}

Answer: Certainly! Here's how you can translate those OPL constraints to Pyomo using pyomo's ConstraintList:

```
from pyomo.environ import 

ConcreteModel, Var, Constraint, Param, ConstraintList

# Assuming you have already defined 'suppliers', 'M', 'x', and 'q'

model = ConcreteModel()

# Define variables
model.x = Var(["F", "other_indices"], suppliers)
model.q = Var(["F", "other_indices"], suppliers)

# Define parameter M
model.M = Param(initialize=M)

# Create a ConstraintList
model.constraints = ConstraintList()

# Add constraints to the ConstraintList
for j in suppliers:
    model.constraints.add(expr=model.x["F", j] >= model.q["F", j] / model.M)
    model.constraints.add(expr=model.q["F", j] >= model.x["F", j] / model.M)
```